# Patch without changing owner and group

Tags: patch, chown

I've got a file owned by a non-root user:

```
# ls -l example.php
-rw------- 1 foo bar ... example.php
```

I just applied a patch with a command like

```
patch -p0 <<-EOF
--- .../example.php.orig 2012-06-20 15:07:13.000000000 +0200
+++ .../example.php  2012-06-20 15:43:05.000000000 +0200
...
EOF
```

as root and the target file user and group were both changed to `root`. I couldn't find any reference to this in the `man` pages.

Is there a way to **leave the file ownership as before** without using `su`, `sudo`, or `chown`?

- `su` seems unable to specify a group.
- `sudo -u foo patch ...` runs fine, but sets the wrong group.
- `sudo -u foo -g bar patch ...` returns `Sorry, user root is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/patch' as foo:bar on hostname`. This might be because user `foo` is not a member of group `bar`.
- `chown` would mean having to store the permissions before running `patch`, adding another two lines of code.

Comment: Can you show an example with file ownership and the exact command you run?  I'm a bit surprised to see that user root is not allowed to execute ... as foo.  That would indicate you are logged in as root and then executing sudo.  Usually you run sudo to gain elevated privileges.  So to help you we need to know who owns the file, who is executing the patch command etc.

Comment: @Bram: Clarified the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`patch` creates new file, that's why it holds effective user credentials.

A workaround: use `patch -o` to have temporary file created, then simply `cat` tmp file to original file.